# Display all subcategories for a product category in woocommerce

Tags: categories, plugins

Is there a way to add a shortcode to a page, in order for that to display the subcategories of a category? (not the products themselves)

I know that you can configure Woocommerce to display it, but I need to have it on a page, so that I can hide it via UAM plugin.

I am aware of the shortcode:

> [product_categories number="12" parent="0"]

But that displays only the top categories. I need the child categories of one top category.

Answer (score 3):

That's easy. Just use the same shortcode and in the parent attribute, place the ID of the parent category. You'll get out its sub-categories as a result:

[product_categories number="12" parent="57"]

Comment: Sorry but this will only show the parent category and not their children

Answer (score 1):

You could easily display the category widget from WooCommerce in a page template using :

```
the_widget('WC_Widget_Product_Categories');
```

The code with parameters can be find in `woocommerce\classes\widgets\class-wc-widget-product-categories.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i would rather solve it without the use of PHP code. I hope there is a way.